# Why does when installing chromadb, I'm stuck with preparing wheel metadata? How do I fix this?

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api, langchain

I am trying to use OpenAI alongside chromadb and langchain. However, when I go to install chromadb, I get stuck with "preparing wheel metadata" for hours. Is this an error? Is there a way around it? See image for reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUtjH.png)

I tried using "

```
pip install chromadb"
```

, and got stuck on preparing wheel data for hours. I'm trying to install it so I can use its features for my project.

Comment: py -m pip install chromadb